# Why is my function always outputting "invalid" as a result?

Tags: python, function

I am learning python. In this context, I do an exercise in which I need to perform a series of test on a string. If these checks are met, python should output "Valid", if not "Invalid".

Here is my code, with the comments describing the goal of each functions:

```
import string

def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    if is_valid(plate):
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

# Function "main" calls the "is_valid" function

def is_valid(s):
    if lenght_valid(s) == True and starts_alpha(s) == True and check_ponctuation(s) == False:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Function "is_valid" calls all the other function checking single cirterias

def lenght_valid(s):
    if len(s) > 6 or len(s) < 2:
       return False
    else:
       return True

# Function "lengt_valid" check the propoer lenght (2 characters min., 6 max.)


def starts_alpha(s):
    s = s[0:2]
    if s.isalpha():
       return True
    else:
       return False

# Function "starts_alpha" check that the first two characters are letters

def check_ponctuation(s):
    return (character in string.punctuation for character in s)

# Function "check_punctuation" checks if punctuation is present. If "True" then this will be rejected in the above function

main()
```

I do not understand why it always outputs "Invalid". I tested "KA" and "KOKO" and these should be valid, however, these are not valid.

Comment: `... == True` is an antipattern. Just test `...` directly: `if length_valid(s) and starts_alpha(s) and not check_punctation(s): ...`

Comment: Ho! I am sorry for not having tested this component specifically. I would have seen if I would have done that. but I have read in other posts of stack overflow that this what check_punctuation does?

Comment: What do you mean by "antipattern"?

Comment: An antipattern is something you shouldn't do.

Comment: and instead of doing all those tests to return true or false, you can just return the test

Comment: For that matter, `if <condition>: return True; else return False` is also an antipattern. Just do `return <condition>`. (if the condition itself is not already a boolean value, you can make it so explicitly: `return bool(condition)`.

Comment: Example: The complete function body of `starts_alpha` could be replaced by `return s[0:2].isalpha()`.

Comment: Many thanks for this comments. I am not able to understand these full however. I feel you want me to write less code. Less conditions. This is the only thing I gather for now. But many thanks. Hopefully this will get clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function, check_ponctuation is returning a generator, not a boolean result.

```
def check_ponctuation(s):
    return (character in string.punctuation for character in s)
```

This function is not doing what you think it is doing.

Presumably, you've missed an any() call.

This code is what it should be:

```
def check_ponctuation(s):
    return any(character in string.punctuation for character in s)
```

The reason that any is needed, is that if you call

```
return (character in string.punctuation for character in s)
```

by itself, you're returning a generator object which could result in unexpected behavior.

Instead, by using any(), you can check to see if your string contains any punctuation and return a true or a false based on that.

Here's some information about any() in python and how it works:

"The any() function returns True if any item in an iterable are true, otherwise it returns False.

If the iterable object is empty, the any() function will return False."

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_any.asp

Edit: Changed the word undefined to unexpected

Comment: Many thanks! This works! I had indeed seen the "any" in one answer from stackoverflow, but I thought it was an error from the person posting and got rid of it...

Comment: I am currently not able to accept your answer, but I will, because know this works, many thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you :) good luck with your python learning!  any() is an incredible function that can be used in many different ways, definitely worth learning!

Comment: OK so I was finally able to accept your answer, many thanks again, I will look up "any". But I must say that I find the official documentation of python a bit hard to get.

Comment: for sure! yeah it honestly can get pretty confusing.  Kudos to you for learning it! and thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: Hoalalaa...........I was typically looking at it and thinking that it was significantly clearer....ok...well...another thing to correct or pay attention to I guess....thanks.

Comment: @Kelsey It's not accurate to say that returning a generator results in undefined behavior. There is nothing wrong or undefined about returning generators as far as the language is concerned, it's just not the behavior the OP wanted.

Comment: perhaps unexpected behavior would've been the better term to use